# Can't Convert sql connection string to byte[]

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, cryptography, arrays

I am trying to convert an sqlstring that contains normal characters and '_' , ';', and '='
and when i try to do this:

```
Byte[] byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

I get this error message

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Additonal:
-I am using this to encrypt an sqlstring
-my decrypt which uses this same function works fine but when trying to convert back for encryption it fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly your problem

```
Byte[] byt = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string

You are trying to convert from a base64 string which you aren't supplying

```
byte[] byt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```

Convert back to a string

```
string value = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byt);
```